# Reapplying migrations after database drop

Tags: cookiecutter-django

If I need, want to drop my database and start over, what is involved or how do I apply the migrations? I don't want to start over from scratch installing the whole cookiecutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a backup of your entire project. Make sure, to make a backup of the virtual environment as well!
Go through your apps and delete all files in the 'migrations' folder but the '**init**.py' files.

Now here is an often overlooked and kinda clumsy part: 
Go to your virtual environment. Under
/lib/pythonx.x/site-packages/allauth/migrations/ delete the migration files, leave the **init**.py file. 
Same is for /lib/pythonx.x/site-packages/socialaccount/migrations/

Then just do as you would with a new project i.e.
createdatabase
createsuperuser
makemigrations

That should be it!